# How to get counting of documents from another collection in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to know how can I get a specific field value?

In my mysql :

```
select *, 
(select count(qty) from score where id = a.id) as d_qty 
from mlbhitters as a order by no desc
```

In my mongoose :

```
 this.aggregate([
    {
        $match:options.query
    }, 
    {
        $sort:{
            no:-1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit:options.limit
    }
]).exec(callback);
```

Here is the point that where should I insert sub query in my mongoose?

```
(select count(qty) from score where id = a.id) as d_qty
```

MongoDB is hard for me to understand how it works :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering simplest scenario where you have two collections like below:

```
db.col1.save({ _id: 1 })
db.col2.save({ col1_id: 1 })
db.col2.save({ col1_id: 1 })
db.col2.save({ col1_id: 1 })
```

you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) to get the data from `col2` into `col1` by specifying which fields define the "relationship" and then you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get the number of elements, try:

```
db.col1.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "col2",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "col1_id",
            as: "col2docs"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            col2size: { $size: "$col2docs" }
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "col2size" : 3 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Micki Thanks to you I've learned lookup methods~ Merry christmas :)